# Reactjs handle browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

How to handle page refresh in reactjs.Like I have a url :

> /main/books/page

Currently on browser through react-router but when I refresh the page or put another url in address bar manually I want to have previous url in bar to get loaded not the new one after some conditions check.

E.g. 
If a logged in user try to access /login or /signup routes then they get redirected to url they are comming from i.e. last or previous url they visited.

Basically my question is how to fetch previously visited url in browser before the browser is reloaded or redirected to another url manually?

Comment: How about using higher order components for it?Something like authchecker.js initialised in app.js so that you can handle based on logged in or not ,you can route

Comment: You're talking about react-router, but from question it looks, like you want to use whole page refresh for some reason, do I read you well?

Comment: You can use simply https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content or fetch (cached content will be loaded faster after changing URL).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the authentication in the `componentDidMount` function and redirect user using `history` like this :

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if(!this.props.autheticated) {
    this.props.history.push('/login')
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually what I want is o fetch the last browser url, not custom url. Thats main issue

Comment: @kshitij you can store your history urls somewhere - local storage /indexedDB, so even after refresh it will be there. Then simply use fetch()

Comment: @kshitij yes you have to save the latest position in somewhere and you can also use `this.props.history.goBack()`

Answer (score 0):

in login page,

```
componentDidMount(){
  if(isUserLoggedIn){
this.props.history.goBack()
```

}
}

or use
this.props.history.pop()